# Error constructing an Object from a custom C++ Library in Arduino

Tags: c++, arduino

I attempted to compile this Arduino sketch with a custom library in it (jtaServoController), and the Arduino IDE claims that my constructor in the Arduino sketch was written incorrectly (more precisely, 'jtaServoControllerFour' does not name a type).

```
#include <jtaServoController.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_PWMServoDriver.h>

Adafruit_PWMServoDriver pwm1 = Adafruit_PWMServoDriver(0x40);

#define SERVOMIN  0
#define SERVOMAX  600

jtaServoControllerFour pointerFinger(1,2,3,4);   //line in question


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pwm1.begin();
  pwm1.setPWMFreq(60);
}

void loop() {
  pointerFinger.jtaSetPWMFour(300,400,500,600);
}
```

My Question is whether the line in question actually is written wrong or is there an issue in another part of my code?-probably in the library itself which I have below. (btw I found the information for constructing an object in the Arduino tutorial on libraries).

These are the Header and .cpp files respectively:

```
#ifndef jtaServoController_h
#define jtaServoController_h

#include "Wire.h"
#include "Adafruit_PWMServoDriver.h"
#include "Arduino.h"

class jtaServoControllerFour
{
    public:
        jtaServoControllerFour(int servo1, int servo2, int servo3, int servo4);
        void jtaSetPWMFour(unsigned int servo41, unsigned int servo42, unsigned int servo43, unsigned int servo44);
    private:
        int _servoOne;
        int _servoTwo;
        int _servoThree;
        int _servoFour;
};


   #endif
```

CPP file

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "jtaServoController.h"
#include "Adafruit_PWMServoDriver.h"
#include "Wire.h"

jtaServoControllerFour::jtaServoControllerFour(int servoOne, int servoTwo, int servoThree, int servoFour)
{
    _servoOne = servoOne;
    _servoTwo = servoTwo;
    _servoThree = servoThree;
    _servoFour = servoFour;
}

void jtaServoControllerFour::jtaSetPWMFour(int servoFourOne, int servoFourTwo, int servoFourThree, int servoFourFour)
{
    pwm1.setPWM(_servo1, 0, servoFourOne);
    pwm1.setPWM(_servo2, 0, servoFourTwo);
    pwm1.setPWM(_servo3, 0, servoFourThree);
    pwm1.setPWM(_servo4, 0, servoFourFour);
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <jtaServoController.h>
```

You may need to use the following instead (double quotes):

```
#include "jtaServoController.h"
```

And/or check the path to your header file.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename) for the difference between the two.